JavaScript code for web-based audio player application designed to play live radio streams doesnt work on iphone and mozilla firefox
In Wordpress with Hello Elementor, Elementor and Elementor Pro I wrote a custom web-based audio player to play live radio stream but it doesnt work on iphone and Mozilla firefox in all devices.
I tried many things but nothing works. When I switch off enhanced protection off it works. Can someone help me?
(function () {
    const el = {
        'timer': '#timer .elementor-heading-title',
        'duration': '#duration .elementor-heading-title',
        'loading': '#loading',
        'playBtn': '#playBtn',
        'pauseBtn': '#pauseBtn',
        'backward': '#backward',
        'forward': '#forward',
        'bar': '#bar',
        'progress': '#progress',
        'tracker': '#tracker',
        'volBar': '#volBar',
        'volBarPerc': '#volBarPerc',
        'volTracker': '#volTracker',
        'mute': '#mute i',
        'htmlAudio': '#html-audio',
        'live': '#live'
    };

    const elems = {};
    Object.keys(el).forEach((key) => {
        elems[key] = document.querySelector(el[key]);
    });

    /**
     * Radio class containing the state of our stations.
     * Includes all methods for playing, stopping, etc.
     * @param station object with station details ({title, src, howl, ...}).
     */
    var Radio = function (station) {
        var self = this;

        self.station = station;
        self.vol = 1;
        self.duration = 0;
        self.playing = false;

        self.loadtime = 0;

        setInterval(function () {
            var f = self.updateDuration();
        }, 1000);
    };

    Radio.prototype = {

        /**
         * Play a station.
         */
        play: function () {
            var self = this;
            var sound;
            var data = self.station;

            // If we already loaded this track, use the current one.
            // Otherwise, setup and load a new Howl.
            if (data.howl) {
                data.howl.play();

            } else {
                self.newHowl();

                self.station.howl.load();
                self.station.howl.volume(0, self.sid);
                self.sid = self.station.howl.play();
                self.station.howl.seek(0, self.sid);
            }

            self.playing = true;

            // Show the pause button.
            if (data.howl.state(self.sid) === 'loaded') {
                elems.playBtn.style.display = 'none';
                elems.pauseBtn.style.display = 'flex';
            } else {
                elems.loading.style.display = 'flex';
                elems.playBtn.style.display = 'none';
                elems.pauseBtn.style.display = 'none';
            }
        },

        newHowl: function () {
            var self = this;
            self.station.howl = new Howl({
                src: self.station.src, // + '?dt=' + Date.now().toString(),
                html5: true, // A live stream can only be played through HTML5 Audio.
                ext: ['mp3'],
                format: ['mp3'],
                preload: false,
                autoplay: true,
                onplay: function () {
                    // Start updating the progress of the track.
                    requestAnimationFrame(self.step.bind(self));
                    elems.pauseBtn.style.display = 'flex';
                },
                onload: function () {
                    elems.loading.style.display = 'none';
                },
                onpause: function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame(self.step.bind(self));
                },
                onstop: function () {
                },
                onseek: function () {
                    // Start updating the progress of the track.
                    requestAnimationFrame(self.step.bind(self));
                }
            });
        },

        updateDuration: function () {

            var self = this;
            var sound = self.station.howl;

            if (!sound) {
                return -1;
            }
            console.log(sound.state(self.sid));
            if (sound.state(self.sid) === 'loading') {
                self.loadtime++;
            }
            if (sound.state(self.sid) !== 'loaded') {
                elems.loading.style.display = 'flex';
                elems.playBtn.style.display = 'none';
                elems.pauseBtn.style.display = 'none';

                if (sound.state(self.sid) !== 'loading' || self.loadtime > 5) { // || self.duration > 0) {
                    console.log("new")
                    self.station.howl.unload(self.sid);
                    // self.station.howl = null;
                    //
                    // self.newHowl();
                    self.duration = 0;
                    self.loadtime = 0;
                    self.station.howl.load();
                    self.sid = self.station.howl.play();
                    self.station.howl.volume(0, self.sid);
                    self.station.howl.seek(0, self.sid);
                    self.playing = true;

                }
                return 0;
            }

            elems.loading.style.display = 'none';
            if (self.playing) {
                elems.playBtn.style.display = 'none';
                elems.pauseBtn.style.display = 'flex';
            } else {
                elems.playBtn.style.display = 'flex';
                elems.pauseBtn.style.display = 'none';
            }

            self.duration++;
            self.station.howl.volume(self.vol, self.sid);

            return 1;
        },

        /**
         * Pause the currently playing track.
         */
        pause: function () {
            var self = this;

            // Get the Howl we want to manipulate.
            var sound = self.station.howl;

            if (!sound) return;

            // Puase the sound.
            sound.pause(self.sid);

            self.playing = false;

            // Show the play button.
            elems.playBtn.style.display = 'flex';
            elems.pauseBtn.style.display = 'none';
        },

        goLive: function () {
            var self = this;

            var sound = self.station.howl;

            if (!sound) return;

            var s = self.duration - 1;
            if (s < 0) s = 0;

            sound.seek(s, self.sid);
        },

        jump: function (direction) {
            var self = this;

            var sound = self.station.howl;

            if (!sound) return;

            var jump = 10

            if (direction === 'backward') {
                jump *= -1
            }

            var newSeek = sound.seek(self.sid) + jump;

            if (newSeek < 0) {
                newSeek = 0;
            }

            if (newSeek > self.duration) {
                newSeek = self.duration - 1;
                if (newSeek < 0) newSeek = 0;
            }

            if (sound.state() === 'loaded') {
                sound.seek(newSeek, self.sid);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Stop a station's live stream.
         */
        stop: function () {
            var self = this;

            // Get the Howl we want to manipulate.
            var sound = self.station.howl;

            if (!sound) return;

            // Stop the sound.
            if (sound) {
                sound.unload(self.sid);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Set the volume and update the volume slider display.
         * @param  {Number} val Volume between 0 and 1.
         */
        volume: function (val) {
            var self = this;

            if (!self.station.howl) return;

            // Update the display on the slider.
            elems.volBarPerc.style.width = (val * 100) + '%';
            elems.volTracker.style.left = (val * 100) + '%';

            if (val === 0) {
                elems.mute.classList.remove("player-fill-volume");
                elems.mute.classList.add("player-fill-mute");

                self.volSave = self.station.howl.volume(self.sid);
                if (self.volSave < 0.1) self.volSave = 0.1;

            } else {
                elems.mute.classList.remove("player-fill-mute");
                elems.mute.classList.add("player-fill-volume");
            }


            // Update the global volume (affecting all Howls).
            self.station.howl.volume(val, self.sid);
            self.vol = val;
        },

        mute: function () {
            var self = this;
            if (!self.station.howl) return;

            if (self.station.howl.volume(self.sid) === 0) {
                self.volume(self.volSave);
            } else {
                self.volume(0);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Seek to a new position in the currently playing track.
         * @param  {Number} per Percentage through the song to skip.
         */
        seek: function (per) {
            var self = this;

            // Get the Howl we want to manipulate.
            var sound = self.station.howl;

            if (!sound) return;

            // Convert the percent into a seek position.
            //if (sound.playing()) {
            var newSeek = self.duration * per;

            if (self.duration - newSeek < 2) {
                newSeek = self.duration - 1;
            }
            if (newSeek < 0) newSeek = 0;
            sound.seek(newSeek, self.sid);
            //}
        },

        /**
         * The step called within requestAnimationFrame to update the playback position.
         */
        step: function () {
            var self = this;

            // Get the Howl we want to manipulate.
            var sound = self.station.howl;

            if (sound) {
                var seek = sound.seek(self.sid) || 0;


                // if (self.duration > 0){ // && sound.state() === "loaded" && seek <= self.duration) {
                // Determine our current seek position.
                var perc = ((seek / self.duration) * 100) || 100;
                var diff = self.duration - seek;
                var timertxt = '';

                if (diff < 0) {
                    seek = self.duration - 1;
                    if (seek < 0) seek = 0;
                    sound.seek(seek, self.sid);

                    perc = 100;
                    elems.live.classList.add('now');
                } else if (diff < 2) {
                    perc = 100;
                    elems.live.classList.add('now');
                } else {
                    elems.live.classList.remove('now');
                    timertxt = '- ' + self.formatTime(Math.round(diff))
                }

                elems.timer.innerHTML = timertxt;
                elems.duration.innerHTML = self.formatTime(Math.round(self.duration));

                if (!window.trackerDown) {
                    elems.progress.style.width = perc.toString() + '%';
                    elems.tracker.style.left = perc.toString() + '%';
                }
                // }
            }


            // If the sound is still playing, continue stepping.
            //if (sound.playing()) {
            requestAnimationFrame(self.step.bind(self));
            //}
        },

        /**
         * Format the time from seconds to M:SS.
         * @param  {Number} secs Seconds to format.
         * @return {String}      Formatted time.
         */
        formatTime: function (secs) {
            var minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60) || 0;
            var seconds = (secs - minutes * 60) || 0;

            return minutes + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
        }

    };

    window.trackerDown = false;
    window.volTrackerDown = false;
    window.trackerPerc = 0;

    // Setup our new radio and pass in the stations.
    var player = new Radio(
        {
            freq: '100.6',
            title: "Nostos Radio",
            src: 'https://rdst.win:48051', // + Date.now().toString(), 'https://neos.win:37878/stream?type=.mp3',
            howl: null
        }
    );


    // Bind our player controls.

    // Main Buttons

    elems.playBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        player.play();
    });
    elems.pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        player.pause();
    });

    elems.live.addEventListener('click', function () {
        player.goLive();
    });

    elems.backward.addEventListener('click', function () {
        player.jump('backward');
    });

    elems.forward.addEventListener('click', function () {
        player.jump('forward');
    });


    // Progress Bar

    function getPercent(event, bar) {
        let x = event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX;
        let barRect = bar.getBoundingClientRect();
        let per;
        if (x < barRect.left) {
            per = 0;
        } else if (x > barRect.left + barRect.width) {
            per = 1;
        } else {
            per = (x - barRect.left) / barRect.width;
        }

        return per;
    }


    elems.bar.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
        if(!player.station.howl) return;
        window.trackerPerc = getPercent(event, elems.bar);
        // player.seek(per);
        window.trackerDown = true;
        elems.progress.style.width = (window.trackerPerc * 100).toString() + '%';
        elems.tracker.style.left = (window.trackerPerc * 100).toString() + '%';
    });

    elems.tracker.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        if(!player.station.howl) return;
        window.trackerDown = true;
        elems.progress.style.width = (window.trackerPerc * 100).toString() + '%';
        elems.tracker.style.left = (window.trackerPerc * 100).toString() + '%';
    });
    elems.tracker.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
        if(!player.station.howl) return;
        window.trackerDown = true;
        elems.progress.style.width = (window.trackerPerc * 100).toString() + '%';
        elems.tracker.style.left = (window.trackerPerc * 100).toString() + '%';
    });

    // Volume

    elems.mute.addEventListener('click', function () {
        player.mute();
    });

    // Set up the event listeners to enable dragging of volume slider.
    elems.volBar.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
        let per = getPercent(event, elems.volBar);
        player.volume(per);
        window.volTrackerDown = true;
    });

    elems.volTracker.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        window.volTrackerDown = true;
    });
    elems.volTracker.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
        window.volTrackerDown = true;
    });


    // Move Bars

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        if(!player.station.howl) return;
        if (window.trackerDown) {
            player.seek(window.trackerPerc);
        }
        window.trackerDown = false;
        window.volTrackerDown = false;
    });
    window.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
        if(!player.station.howl) return;
        if (window.trackerDown) {
            player.seek(window.trackerPerc);
        }
        window.trackerDown = false;
        window.volTrackerDown = false;
    });

    var move = function (event) {
        if(!player.station.howl) return;

        if (window.trackerDown) {
            window.trackerPerc = getPercent(event, elems.bar);
            elems.progress.style.width = (window.trackerPerc * 100).toString() + '%';
            elems.tracker.style.left = (window.trackerPerc * 100).toString() + '%';
            // player.seek(per);
        }

        if (window.volTrackerDown) {
            let per = getPercent(event, elems.volBar);
            player.volume(per);
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', move);

})();
</script>


What debugging have you tried, and does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76055234/howler-js-audio-plays-on-desktop-but-doesnt-play-on-mobile-device-ios-firefox-a
